# lview is undefined when trying to pass content into mat-dialog using viewchild

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to open a CardElement from a dashboard with various content in a dialog popup without losing the data and not having to re-pass it. I was thinking about ViewChild. In a few use cases I saw that the implementation would exactly meet my requirements and so I tried it with this method.

However, I now get spit out in my console that lView is undefined.

I didn't find anything related to this error message that i haven't tried so i openend this question.

[image]

Heres my ViewChild:

```
 @ViewChild('cardElement', { read: ElementRef, static: true}) cardElement: ElementRef;
```

Heres my function for calling the dialog:

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(CardDashDialogComponent, {
      width: '80%',
      maxHeight: '90%',
      data:  this.cardElement,
      panelClass: 'roundedDialog'
    });
  }
```

Heres my CardDashDialogComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-dash-dialog',
  templateUrl: './card-dash-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-dash-dialog.component.css']
})
export class CardDashDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('cardContent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) cardContent: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cardContent.insert(this.data);
  }
}
```

Heres my CardDashDialogComponent.html:

```
<div #cardContent></div>
```